# How to best achieve colour consistency between product imagery and print?

Tags: color

I have to design a brochure for a clothing retailer and ensure the products match the imagery I have so they are consistent in print (colour wise) Whats the best way to achieve consistency between the two?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You're going to need the Pantone colours for the things they print to get the match as close as possible.

Once they give you these, you can use something like http://rgb.to to match Pantone colours to Hex colours you can use in Photoshop.

Sometimes I literally run pallet prints, make sure you set your document up in CMYK and just test a colour in a few shades... Print it out and check it against the garment.

It is unlikely you will ever get it exact. But using pantones is one way you can get it extremely close.